# Understanding candidate key

Tags: database, key, candidate-key

Consider `R(A,B,C,D,E)`
`F = {BC->AE, A->D, D->C, ABD->E}`.
I need to find all candidate key of the schema.
I know that `BA`,`BC`,`BD` are the keys, but i want to know how do discover them.

I saw some answers in [candidate keys from functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718420/candidate-keys-from-functional-dependencies) = but i didn't fully understand them.
form what they suggest, I got `L={B}`, `M={A,C,D}`, `R={E}`
Now i need to add from `M` one at a time to `L`.
I start with `A`, i get `BA`. So `BA->A`, `BA->B` (trivial) and because `A->D` so `BA->D` and because `D->C` we get `BA->C`.
But, how we get `E`?

Comment: the algorithm is one that computes a minimum covering set, meaning a set which covers all dependencies and is minimum among other sets with same property

Comment: "*But, how we get E?*", you did  not use all dependency relations, if you do you will arrive at `E`

Comment: @NikosM. you can point the relation i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adapting the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14595217/3591273

Since we have the functional dependencies: `BC->AE, A->D, D->C, ABD->E`, we have the following superkeys:

- `ABCDE` (All attributes is always a super key)
- `ABCD` (We can get attribute `E` through `ABD -> E`)
- `ABC` (Just add `D` through `A -> D`)
- `ABD` (Just add `C` through `D -> C`)
- `AB` (We can get `D` through `A -> D`, and then we can get `C` through `D -> C`)
- `BC` (We can get `E` through `BC -> E`, and then we can get `C` through `D -> C`)
- `BD` (We can get `C` through `D -> C`, and then we can get `AE` through `BC -> AE`)

(One trick here to realize, is that since `B` **never appears** on the right side of a functional dependency, every key must include `B`, ie key `B` is **independent and cannot be derived from other keys**)

> Now that we have all our super keys, we can see that only the last
>   three are candidate keys. Since the first four can all be trimmed
>   down. But we cannot take any attributes away from the last three
>   superkeys and still have them remain a superkey.

so the minimal keys are `AB`, `BC`, `BD`

**update**

this was a *reduction approach*, i.e succesively reduce the trivial superkey by use of functional dependencies, but one can take the opposite road and use an *augment approach*, i.e start with single trivial keys and augment them with other keys wrt dependency relations untill keys become superflous

Comment: * `AB` (We can get `D` through `A -> D`, and then we can get `C` through `D -> C`) but how we get E?

Comment: @user3729959, see above that line, ie through `ABD -> E` it is kind of recursive, you see?

Comment: @user3729959, once we have `ABD` then we can get `E`, ok